# Exception in thread "Thread-8" java.lang.StackOverflowError at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)

Tags: java, netty

```
`Exception in thread "Thread-8" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
'''
'''
'''
'''
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.newTaskQueue0(NioEventLoop.java:279)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.newTaskQueue(NioEventLoop.java:150)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.\<init\>(NioEventLoop.java:138)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.newChild(NioEventLoopGroup.java:146)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.newChild(NioEventLoopGroup.java:37)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.\<init\>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:84)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.\<init\>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:58)
at io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup.\<init\>(MultithreadEventLoopGroup.java:52)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.\<init\>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:96)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.\<init\>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:91)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.\<init\>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:72)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.\<init\>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:52)
at handling.mina.ServerConnection.\<init\>(ServerConnection.java:36)`
```

The error is reported when executing the following code

```
this.bossGroup = (EventLoopGroup)new NioEventLoopGroup(1);
```

The problem exists at deployment time and does not exist when running within IDEA
The java version is "1.8.0_351", it doesn't seem to be a problem in other versions
Who knows what the problem is?

Comment: No repeats in the stack trace?

Comment: A stackoverflow in a classloader is a rare sight I would say. Either you're doing some serious classloader fiddling, use a library that does or it's a bug in the Java version you're using. If it doesn't occur in other versions then I'd assume the latter and I'd not bother with the "why?" but just switch to another runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Adjust your stack size in jvm option from `-Xss=256k` to `-Xss=512K` it is possible you need to increase your stack space .

The `java.lang.StackOverflowError` is a runtime error that indicates that the application stack is not terminate after a finite number of recursive calls. As the base condition is never met, the recursion carries on infinitely.

Commonly occurs when the application stack continues to grow until it reaches the maximum limit. Some of the causes:

- Deep or infinite recursion - If a method calls itself recursively without a terminating condition.
- Cyclic relationships between classes - If a class `A` instantiates an object of class `B`, which in turn instantiates an object of class `A`.
- Memory intensive applications - Applications that rely on resource heavy objects such as XML documents, GUI or java2D classes.

for example

```
public class StackOverflowErrorExample {
    public void print(int myInt) {
        System.out.println(myInt);
        print(myInt);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StackOverflowErrorExample example = new StackOverflowErrorExample();
        example.print(0);
    }
}
```

method `print()` causes an infinite recursion which you could inspect in the stack trace as `(...java:3, ...java:4)` when you identify it where the error is caused you need to set a proper condition to avoid errors.

```
...
at StackOverflowErrorExample.print(StackOverflowErrorExample.java:3)
at StackOverflowErrorExample.print(StackOverflowErrorExample.java:4)
at StackOverflowErrorExample.print(StackOverflowErrorExample.java:4)
at StackOverflowErrorExample.print(StackOverflowErrorExample.java:4)
at StackOverflowErrorExample.print(StackOverflowErrorExample.java:4)
```

Additionally you could have **multiple versions** of netty on the class path. Ensure you only have one.

then your app should look something like:

```
@Inject private lateinit var configuration: RSEEnvironment
@Inject private lateinit var channelHandler: LoginChannelHandler
private val bossGroup = NioEventLoopGroup(1)
private val workerGroup = NioEventLoopGroup(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors())

private lateinit var future: ChannelFuture
override fun startUp()
{
    val hostAddress = configuration.getString("default_host")
    val hostPort = configuration.getInt("default_port")
    bootstrap = ServerBootstrap()
    bootstrap
        .group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
        .channel(NioServerSocketChannel::class.java)
        .childHandler(channelHandler)
        .option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
        .option(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true)
    future = bootstrap.bind(hostAddress, hostPort).syncUninterruptibly()
    future.channel().closeFuture().sync()
}
```